# Very basic mudguard question

Tags: fenders, beginner

I have mudguards on my bike as shown here:
[image: My Bike!]

Firstly, I don't even know what the metal spoke-like things attaching it to the bike are called. Do they have a name?

Secondly, what do I need to attach them back to the bike. From the non-broken ones it doesn't look like a normal screw, but again not knowing the name means I am not getting very far with google.

Lastly, out of interest, is there a name for this type of mudguard and is it an old/out of date type of mudguard.

Comment: The "metal spoke-like things" are generally called "stays". Close up pictures of the attachment point, for both the broken and non-broken spots would be very helpful.

Comment: Looks like SKS (formerly ESGE) fenders.  Unfortunately, the bolts that hold the stays to the fenders are kind of specialized -- a headless bolt with a hold drilled through it.  But if you Google "SKS fender replacement parts" you'll get some hits.  Try here: http://www.amazon.com/SKS-Eyebolt-Nut-Fenders-8-Piece/dp/B0089AX9T2/ref=pd_sim_sbs_sg_1

Comment: (I bought a nearly identical pair of SKS P45 fenders in July.)

Comment: @freiheit thank you for clarifying the name. I was slow and getting back, so someone else seems to have answered in terms of attaching, but thank you.

Comment: @DanielRHicks thank you for the link, finding the name of the item is always the most annoying bit, so ta :)

Comment: Yeah, I had to hunt around quite a bit.  I vaguely remembered that the name was something like "ESGE" but didn't remember it exactly, so had to hunt around until I found a mention of it.   And then found several mentions that it had changed to SKS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mudguards (typically called fenders in the US) are a great feature and come in many varieties. The fenders you have are full-coverage fenders and are likely aluminum. Metal fenders are still quite common (and in my opinion, fenders are an essential addition to any bike if you live where it rains. [Velo Orange](http://www.velo-orange.com) manufactures many sizes and styles that are affordable.)

The fenders are held to the bike via fender stays (long aluminum rods) and are mounted directly at the fork crown in the front and the brake bridge and chainstay bridge/bottom bracket shell in the rear.
[image: Full Fenders]

Fender stays are usually mounted to threaded bosses (with an M5 or M6 cap screw) integrated into the front and rear dropouts (or near the dropouts.) In situations where you don't have dedicated bosses, you can use p-clamps to mount them securely.
[image: P Clamp Mount] [image: Honest-to-goodness p clamps]

At the other end of the stay there is a nut and an eye bolt which allow the distance between your tire and the fender to be adjusted (10mm minimum!) Note: There are many different methods for attaching fender stays, but this is what your fenders utilize.
[image: Fender Stay Hardware]

To install, you simply put the eye bolt onto the fender stay, push the threaded part through the hole on the mounting tab, and tighten the nut down to secure the stay. Do everything loosely at first, then adjust the distance from the fender to the tire and center it.

[Here](http://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/index.php?category=1794) is a link to an online vendor, but most bike shops will have this hardware on hand.

Comment: It seems to me that "mudguards" are only more commonly called "fenders" here in the US. It seems very common for people in Great Britain to call them "mudguards."

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the name of flange on the fender itself, not where it attaches to the bike.

Comment: @jimirings that's a good point. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: @Aaron He's definitely asking about the stays and mounting hardware. The tabs that support the eye bolts are riveted or welded to the fender and aren't generally replaceable. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @WTHarper My bad, he's asking about the spoke-like parts, not the flanges, you are correct. And anything is replaceable if you know how to weld!

Comment: Hi. Firstly, very sorry for the incredibly slow reply. To clarify, I was talking about how the stays (which is what another commenter said the spoke-like things are called) attach the fender/mudguard, not how they attach to the bike, since they are still happily attached at the centre of the wheel.

Thank you for the reply, it covered all I needed and more, so very useful :)